# Merging/Combining an image and text file side by side

Tags: file, image-processing, merge, automation

Is there any way to combine two different files (text, image) side by side? output as an image or pdf file etc...?
I have found methods for similar image files and the system could be automated using a bash script. Am looking for similar thing.
I have frames from a video file and respective sensors data in other text file. I need to combine image info along with the sensor data in one file. Output could be anything image, pdf etc...
Image file are having naming sequence 0001.png

Comment: There are countless ways to do that. You should decide what you want and not just request any output... your question is too broad and off-topic anyway. [ask]  PDF for example is exactly for things like that. Putting texts and images into some layout.

Comment: In those countless ways, can you give at least one example of doing it autonomously using a script? Instead of critisizing the question, i have described in the simplest way i can. Consider a cat pic along with a text file containing text "This is a cat". How to combine both of them in a single file?

Comment: what platform are you looking for OpenCV, skimage, PIL, ImageMagick, etc... @NabeehaDeedar

Comment: you did not even specify a operating system. why would I spend time on giving you a solution that might not even work for you? it's like asking a matchmaker for a new partner without telling if you're male or female, straight or gay.

Comment: @Piglet Hey, some folks dangle both ways :-)

Comment: @Piglet Anyone who knows the keyword 'bash script' would understand what am talking about.

Comment: @MarkSetchell yeah, that would be virtual machine either linux in windows or windows in linux ;)

Comment: @JeruLuke am working on linux mint.

Comment: Last think I'll say on that (not here go argue): Bash is available on several operating systems and virtual machines are usually not the standard way for people. I can't tell my customers to run my shit in a virtual machine e.g.,... I'm just saying that you should not leave out details just because you assume someone knows what you need.
your question is still off-topic so just be happy that Mark was bored at the right time and spoonfed you with a complete solution ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With **ImageMagick** which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows:

Start with `picture.jpg`

[image]

And a text file called `description.txt`

```
These are some funky cogs I found on the Internet some place.

Newlines are ok, and the text gets smaller the more you add.
```

Then do this:

```
# Get width and height of picture
read w h < <(convert picture.jpg -format '%w %h' info:-)

# Put text on grey background and append to right of image
convert -background lightgray -size ${w}x${h} -gravity center label:@description.txt picture.jpg +swap +append result.jpg
```

[image]

---

There are many other possibilities and techniques:

```
geom=$(convert -format %G picture.jpg info:)
convert -background lightgray -size $geom -gravity center -fill blue label:'Cogs!' picture.jpg +swap +append result.jpg
```

[image]

---

```
convert -background darkgray -size $geom -gravity center -fill magenta  label:'Cogs!' picture.jpg +append -bordercolor black -border 10 result.jpg
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what am looking for :). Thanks